# Running total within a category in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to calculate a running total in Microsoft Access and could really need some help.

Basically I have the below table containing three columns:

1. Item
2. Inventory Position
3. Multiple

[image]

I need a four-column (let's call this `OnhandAgg`) that does a running total calculation per item.

The first record within an item should start the running total calculation with Inventory position + Multiple. Thereafter the remaining records within the items should be a running total calculation with last record value + multiple.

When having looped through all records within an item it should restart the running total.

The end result should look something similar to this - I have added an auto number also which should also be a part of the first table.

[image]

Comment: How should the records be ordered? Does the table contain a primary key which could be used to order the records?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: I have tried to implement a dsum syntax from this site, but cannot get the dsum logic to work:

https://theaccessbuddy.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/using-ms-access-to-create-a-running-total-or-a-cumulative-sum-grouped-data-part-2-of-2/

I have added an extra column with the following syntax:

OnhandAgg: DSUM(“[Multiple]”; “PurchaseLines”; “[Item]=’”&[Item]&”’ AND [No]<=”& [No])

But I keep getting a syntax error. Also I am not sure how to start with the first summing field as it has to combine inventorypos + multiple whereas the following sum fields should be a summing + multiple

Comment: Lee Mac - I have added a column No. But overall it should just be sorted based on item.

Comment: Shouldn't row 16 show OnhandAgg value of 190?

Comment: Is this truly representative data? Will InventoryPos and Multiple really be same value for all records in group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell about its efficiency but it works:

```
select t.*,
(select sum(Multiple) from tablename where Item = t.Item and [No] <= t.[No]) +
(select InventoryPos from tablename where Item = t.Item and [No] = (
  select min([No]) from tablename where Item = t.Item)
)
from tablename as t
```

Answer (score 0):

This output can be easily produced with a report. It might perform faster than nested query or domain aggregate function on a large dataset.

1. set a Grouping on Item, include textbox named tbxIP bound to InventoryPos in header
2. in Detail section place a textbox named tbxRS bound to Multiple with RunningSum set to OverGroup (can set Visible = No)
3. in Detail section place textbox with expression `=tbxIP + tbxRS`
4. if you really want appearance of table, can include textboxes for Item and InventoryPos and Multiple in Detail section and set Item Group header as not visible and place labels in Page header to serve as column headers